# requestcontextholder concurrent access

Tags: spring-webflow-2, thread-local-storage

I am using below code in my spring webflow application running on weblogic server.

`RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext()
                .getExternalContext().getNativeRequest()).getSession()`

I know that `RequestContextHolder` uses `ThreadLocal` to store the `requestContext` during start and resume steps.

Now coming to the question is there any remote possibility that one thread may access `requestContext` of other thread (may be because thread is being reused by weblogic or beacuse of some other reason) ?

Comment: Finally found root cause of threading issue, The SWF version (2.2.1) had a bug. Its ExpressionParser is not thread-safe [JIRA Link](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF-1437). Upgarding SWF to 2.3.0 solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to SWF 2.3.0 solved the issue (data shared between threads)
The SWF version (2.2.1) had a bug. Its ExpressionParser was not thread-safe ([JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF-1437)).